# "Error occurred during the signature verification. Repository i not updated... " while sudo apt-get update on Hummingboard

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

I get an Error when i run "sudo apt-get update":

> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.solid-build.xyz ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1508672008 Failed to fetch https://repo.solid-build.xyz/debian/jessie/bsp-imx6/./Release Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I guess i need a new key, but how can i get it? Thx for any help.

System: Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie) with MATE 1.8.1 Desktop Environment

I tried:

```
apt-key list
```

and found 3 expired keys, so i tried:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys [KEY]
```

I did this with all 3 expired keys but again with apt-key list they didnt changed. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The expired Key is a known issue from Hummingboard. You can find information on their wiki: https://wiki.solid-run.com/doku.php?id=products:a38x:software:os:debian
After installing the recommended solidrun-keyring_*_all.deb it changed 1 of 3 expired keys, once updated with a system crash and a restart including again updating the system, lead to a working system. And all keys were updated after second update.